# When using hook_form_alter() and additional submit functions, can one reference a php file for the submit callback?

Tags: hooks, forms

The following code works.

```
function bleh_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {
    case "webform_client_form_13":
      $form['#submit'][] = 'bleh_community_submit';
      break;
  }
}

function bleh_community_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Do some stuff here.
}
```

However, is it possible to use code similar to the following one, where the form submit function calls a PHP script (e.g. bleh_community_submit.php) containing the form submission handler?

```
function bleh_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case "webform_client_form_13":
      $form['#submit'][] = 'bleh_community_submit.php';
      break;
  }
}

// Separate .php file in the module directory with the 
   additional bleh_community_submit function

function bleh_community_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Do some stuff here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do something like

```
require_once('bleh_community_submit.php');
```

then call the callback function as per normal?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is AFAIK no way to do so. You pretty much have to leave these functions in the .module file (You could place them in a second file which you include always, but that makes no sense performance wise).

Drupal 7 initially had a class *and* function registry, and it automatically scanned all your files for classes and functions and included them automatically (given that you used drupal_function_exists() for all functions that might be in an include file. But that turned out to be too fragile, too hard to maintain and actually made the site slower when using a opcode cache like APC. So the function part was removed again.